# Is there a way to convert .xif files (created with Xerox Pagis app on old win 32 OS) to pdf?

Tags: pdf, convert

I need to convert some 100 .xif files to pdf. As far as I know the only way is to find a 32bit PC with NT or Win2000 and install the Pagis (scanner app of Xerox).xif.
Is there a better way using a linux app?
Is there a linux app that can open .xif files?

Comment: There are online converters. https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=xif+to+pdf+converter&atb=v273-1&ia=web

Answer (score 1):

## convert (from ImageMagick)

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install imagemagick

for i in *.xif ; do convert "$i" "${i%.*}.pdf" ; done
```

If you have an error with `convert` (I had one with Ubuntu 21.04), you can check the following page : [ImageMagick security policy 'PDF' blocking conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998331/imagemagick-security-policy-pdf-blocking-conversion)

## Okular

- Print to file. Export quality is good. I have the impression you lose resolution.

## Gimp

- You can try [GIMP Batch Mode](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/) for multiple files. Not sure you will save time.

**Evince**

- Great for viewing. Export quality is bad when printing to file (PDF)

**Xreader**

- Great for viewing. Export quality is bad when printing to file (PDF)

Some other viewers only show the first page.

Sources :

- http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/XIFF
- [A two pages .xif for tests.](https://web.archive.org/web/19970513215436/http://www.xerox.com/xis/pagis/files/sample1.xif)
- [Batch converting PNG to JPG in linux](https://superuser.com/a/542671/957089)